# Make Django to compile modules out of regular Django project modules

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and I want to encapsulate some items, so I created a python file inside a Django application directory:

[image]

The problem is that Django engine is not compiling this file, so syntax errors are not reported. Django is basically ignoring the file and do not react to changes in it, like it reacts to changes in `models.py`, that causes Django engine to restart.

What do I need to do for Django to consider this file?

Comment: Do you `import` that file anywhere?

Comment: @Chris No, not yet

Comment: Try `import`ing it into your code somewhere. I'm pretty sure that will trigger the behaviour you want.